# Easiest way to rename a metric in datadog?

Tags: statsd, datadog

I'm using a `statsd.timed` to send some time metrics to datadog. These metrics are being used in a few Datadog dashboards. Changing the metric name being sent is straightforward and can be done by updating the name of the metric in the statsd.timed call/decorator in the code, however, the old metric name may already be in use in existing datadog dashboards.

Is there a quick and easy way to rename a metric in Datadog so that all dependencies such as Dashboards using the metric are also updated, without having to go through each dashboard and updating them independently?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Datadog respective dashboard apis to update your metric names in all dashboards? Should theoretically be not too complicated to script out.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#screenboards
https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#timeboards